# LPTHW Ex47 Attribute Error

Tags: python, attributes

I'm working through LPTHW and am stuck on an attribute error for Ex47. I've looked over this site and searched google for help but can't seem to find anything.

The error I get is this:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Users/Donatron/temp/My Python Stuff/projects/ex47/tests/ex47_tests.py", line 26, in test_map
    start.add_paths({'west': west, 'down': down})
  File "/Users/Donatron/temp/My Python Stuff/projects/ex47/ex47/game.py", line 12, in add_paths
    self.paths.update(paths)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update'
```

My "Game" code looks like this:-

```
class Room(object):


    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.paths = []

    def go(self, direction):
        return self.paths.get(direction, None)

    def add_paths(self, paths):
        self.paths.update(paths)
```

And my "test" code looks like this:-

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex47.game import Room

def test_room():
    gold = Room("GoldRoom",
                """This room has gold in it you can grab. There's a
                door to the north.""")
    assert_equal(gold.name, "GoldRoom")
    assert_equal(gold.paths, [])

def test_room_paths():
    center = Room("Center", "Test room in the center.")
    north = Room("North", "Test room in the north.")
    south = Room("South", "Test room in the south.")

    center.add_paths({'north': north, 'south': south})
    assert_equal(center.go('north'), north)
    assert_equal(center.go('south'), south)

def test_map():
    start = Room("Start", "You can go west and down a hole.")
    west = Room("Trees", "There are trees here, you can go east.")
    down = Room("Dungeon", "It's dark down here, you can go up.")

    start.add_paths({'west': west, 'down': down})
    west.add_paths({'east': start})
    down.add_paths({'up': start})

    assert_equal(start.go('west'), west)
    assert_equal(start.go('west').go('east'), start)
    assert_equal(start.go('down').go('up'), start)
```

This is doing my head in!! Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help :-)

Answer (score 1):

`self.paths` should be a `dict` `{}` not  a list

`self.paths = {}`

`dicts` have `get` and `update` methods, your `self.paths` is a list `[]` which do not have an update method, that is why you are getting  the error.

Further up in the error you can see `start.add_paths({'west': west, 'down': down})` which is adding a dict that is passed to `self.paths` which tries to call the `self.paths.update` method but fails as `self.paths` is set to a `list` instead of a `dict {}`.

`return self.paths.get(direction, None)` # using a `dict.get` method

`self.paths.update(paths)` # using `dict.update` method.

`dict.get(direction, None)` returns `None` by default if the `key` does not exist in a `dict`, you can specify any default return value in place of `None`.